# Wordpress WooCommerce - remove variation from cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

So I am using Product Addons extension for WooCommerce that actually uses variations for its "addons".

Product Add-ons adds a variation to the cart (when you choose add on for the product).

I am looking for a way to add an option to remove addon(i.e. variation). This is how variations are loaded on cart page, with the Xs representing where I'd like to add a "remove link"

[image: cart example]
<sub>(source: [lexen.net](http://www.lexen.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/2016-01-21_10-18-07.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! I am using Product Addons for Woocommerce, check this website for example: [link](http://easyengrave.com/)  that also uses this extension. I found out how it works: it adds variations(when you choice addon) for the product. So in cart you have something like: [link](http://www.lexen.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/2016-01-21_10-18-07.jpg). So I am looking for a way to add an option to remove addon(i.e. variation). 
There is how variations are loaded on cart page: [link](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/cart-item-data.php)

Comment: Could you add the screenshots directly in to your question? Click "edit" and then use markdown syntax like so: `![screenshot title](http://linktoscreenshot.png)`

Comment: Sorry, I can't - not enough reputation, 10 is needed

Comment: Do you have a link to an example with the functioning variation add on? I just checked and add ons is not filter `woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link` so if you are truly adding a separate product I don't see how they are removing the link. Also, are you sure this isn't coming from your theme somehow?

Comment: [example](http://www.finarium.com/product/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80/)  Try this one.There are just some customizations, so it can be unclear. Those are input-multiplier addons there. If you choice some of the "addons" and proceed to cart page you will see a product+addons. But those are in fact are just variations that adds additional cost(this is the way "Product Addons" extension works). So is there a way to make an option to remove variations, in particular from cart page?